# how to pass arguments?

Tags: c#

i am writing a small game and i want to pass from a method that will pass it to other method that will do something with that number. here is what i try:

```
  public static int MatchesStart()
   {
       Console.Write("how many matches do you want to play with?");
       string matchesStartingNumber = Console.ReadLine();
       int matchesOpeningNumber = Convert.ToInt32(matchesStartingNumber);

       for (int i = 0; i < matchesOpeningNumber; i++)
       {
           Console.Write("|");
       }

       return matchesOpeningNumber;

   }

   public static int RemoveMatches( *** i want here: matchesOpeningNumber  )
   { 

    ///to do somthing with matchesOpeningNumber.

   }
```

when i try to pass it to the second method its failing.. :(  why is that?

Comment: Well you're not currently calling the second method at all. You need to declare a *parameter* in the second method - and then call the method. It's hard to help you without knowing what you've tried.

Comment: Pick up a C# book. This are basics and I can't imagine how you are going to program a game if you don't know how to define methods.

Answer (score 5):

```
 public static int RemoveMatches(int number )
   { 

    ///to do somthing with matchesOpeningNumber.

   }
```

call it like:

```
  int result = RemoveMatches(matchesOpeningNumber);
```

You should see: 
[Passing Value-Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t0za5es.aspx)

If you are using C# 4.0 or higher, you can also use [Named Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx). In that case your call will be:

```
  int result = RemoveMatches(number: matchesOpeningNumber);
                             ^^^^^^
                             parameter name
```